# How to solve Distributivity of $\lor$ over $\land$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The problem I need to prove is $p \lor (q \land r) \equiv (p \lor q) \land (p \lor r)$

I am trying to get the RHS equivalent to the LHS

So I change

$(p \lor q) \land (p \lor r)$

(using the Golden Rule)

(Golden Rule is- $p \land q \equiv p \equiv q \equiv p \lor q$)

$p \lor q  \equiv p \lor r \equiv (p \lor q) \lor (p \lor r)$

?

?

and I know it ends like

$p \lor (q \equiv r \equiv (q \lor r))$

(the I reintroduce Golden Rule again)

$p \lor (q \land r)$

I am missing a few steps in the middle? but I'm not quite sure what

Comment: You can just construct a truth with tables with all possible combinations of truth values for $p$, $q$, $r$ as there are only $2^3 = 8$ possible combinations

Comment: This is an exercise that needs to be solved with the Golden rule, sorry I forgot to mention that.  Thanks though, that would make my life a lot easier if I could do that

Comment: You have a character that looks to me like three horizontal lines.  Given the way you quote the Golden Rule I cannot figure out what the connective is.  In the first line it should be $\leftrightarrow$ but in your parenthetical Golden Rule is that would not be correct.

Comment: the three horizontal lines is an equivalence, used with \equiv. It holds less tightly than a normal = sign, so parenthesis aren't used as frequent.  Thanks for looking at it though

Comment: But where you define the Golden Rule you say $p \wedge q \equiv p \equiv q \equiv p \vee q$ but it is not true that $p \wedge q \equiv p \vee q$ btw if you put @Ross into a comment I will get a notification that you left it-it only works once per comment.  Since I am commenting on your post I don't need to-you get one anyway.

Comment: Okay, What the golden rule is saying, if there is a $p \land q$ that it can also be equivalent to $\equiv p \equiv q \equiv p \lor q$. So in my exercise $p$ is $p \lor q$ and $q$ is $p \lor r$, so you use the Golden rule to distribute the equivalences across the rest of the equation
@RossMillikan

Comment: Hey I figured it out, thanks for helping though, any attempt is worth honoring, shows you mean well. @Ross

Comment: @RossMillikan - The *Golden Rule* in *equational logic* is an axiom. In order to "read it" correctly, you must take into account *priority* between connectives (highest is $\lnot$, lowest is $\equiv$) and the convention about omission of parentheses (re-introduce them from right to left). So the *GR* rule really is : $(((p \land q) \equiv p) \equiv q) \equiv (p \lor q)$. Ii is hard to believe, but if you check this version, you will find that is a *tautology*...

Answer (score 1):

I'm using George Tourlakis, *Mathematical Logic* (2008); see page 42-43 for the *rules* and page 74 : **2.4.23 Theorem. (Distributivity: $\lor$ over $\land$ and $\land$ over $\lor$)**

> $(p \lor q ) \land (p \lor r)$

$p \lor q \lor p \lor r \equiv p \lor q \equiv p \lor r$

apply the **Golden Rule** (using Equanimity and Leibniz Merged, taht is a "derived rule"; see Tourlakis, page 57, **2.1.16 Theorem. (Eqn + Leib Merged)** :  $C[p := A], A \equiv B \vdash  C[p := B]$; we call it "E+L")

> **NOTE.** Due to the use of $p$ and $q$ in the formulas, I will describe the substitution in the “C-part” as “... sub-formula”

$p \lor p \lor q \lor r \equiv p \lor q \equiv p \lor r$

apply E+L, where the ‘C-part’ is $... \equiv p \lor q \equiv p \lor r$, using the “derived axiom” : $(((p \lor q) \lor p) \lor r) \equiv (((p \lor p) \lor q) \lor r)$ (proved with **Associativity** and **Symmetry** of $\lor$)

$p \lor q \lor r \equiv p \lor q \equiv p \lor r$

apply E+L where the ‘C-part’ is $...\lor q \lor r \equiv p \lor q \equiv p \lor r$, using the axiom **Idempotency of** $\lor$, i.e. $p \lor p \equiv p$

$p \lor q \lor r \equiv p \lor (q \equiv r)$

apply E+L where the ‘C-part’ is $p \lor q \lor r \equiv …$, using the axiom **Distributivity of** $\lor$ **over** $\equiv$, i.e. $p \lor (q \equiv r) \equiv p \lor q \equiv p \lor r$;

Now, read $p \lor q \lor r \equiv p \lor (q \equiv r)$ as $p \lor (q \lor r) \equiv p \lor (q \equiv r)$ and apply **Distributivity of** $\lor$ **over** $\equiv$, i.e. $p \lor (A \equiv B) \equiv p \lor A \equiv p \lor B$, obtaining :

$p \lor (q \lor r \equiv q \equiv r)$

Finally, apply E+L where the ‘C-part’ is $p \lor …$, using the **Golden Rule**, i.e. $(q \lor r \equiv q \equiv r) \equiv q \land r$:

> $p \lor (q \land r)$